# wc_get_product(Product_id) doesn't work in a file called by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I send a variable that contains the `id` of a product through a GET AJAX request to a PHP file and I will return an object (`$product`) with `$product = wc_get_product(Product_id)` but I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Note that when I try the `echo` in this PHP file the content are sent but when I try to send this object I get this error.

When I click this script is launched:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "Data_Product.php",
  data: { 
    ID: $(this).attr("data-product-id")
  }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
  $(".modal").find(".product-details").load("Data_Product.php");
});
```

In data_product.php

```
$product = wc_get_product( $_GET["ID"] );
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A 500 error means the issue is in the PHP code being executed on the server, not the JS. Check that the `ID` value you send is exactly what you expect it to be (which you can do by checking the request in the network tab of the console) and also check your server logs to find the full server side error message which should hopefully have a stack trace you can use to pinpoint the location of the problem

Comment: Your code is just incomplete and untestable, remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**."*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to fix it and found the solution @RoryMcCrossan @ LoicTheAztec

Comment: Hi @RetchakAmine can you post the solution here ?